# JavascriptCore->WebCore->CFNetwork crash on iOS app

Tags: ios, crash, cfnetwork

In one of our apps we are seeing some crashes with the following backtrace.

```
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x36a07202 CFEqual + 41
1   CoreFoundation                      0x00088c49 __CFDictionaryStandardEquateKeys + 37
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00002c3c CFBasicHashFindBucket + 2128
3   CoreFoundation                      0x36a07a8b CFDictionaryGetValue + 82
4   CFNetwork                           0x0001d77b SocketStream::copyProperty(void const*, __CFString const*) + 39
5   CFNetwork                           0x000ae181 CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_CopyProperty(__CFString const*) const + 21
6   CFNetwork                           0x0006b7bf HTTPReadFilter::_streamImpl_CopyProperty(__CFString const*) const + 235
7   CFNetwork                           0x000ae181 CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_CopyProperty(__CFString const*) const + 21
8   CFNetwork                           0x00017e11 NetConnection::willEnqueueRequests() + 65
9   CFNetwork                           0x000678fd HTTPNetConnection::prepareTransmission(HTTPNetStreamInfo*, __CoreWriteStream*) + 21
10  CFNetwork                           0x00017005 NetConnection::enqueue(void*, unsigned char) + 321
11  CFNetwork                           0x0006972d HTTPNetStreamInfo::_streamImpl_Open(CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 57
12  CFNetwork                           0x00069787 non-virtual thunk to HTTPNetStreamInfo::_streamImpl_Open(CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 11
13  CFNetwork                           0x000ae1b5 CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_Open() + 45
14  CFNetwork                           0x0000641b HTTPProtocol::openStream() + 183
15  CFNetwork                           0x0007789d HTTPProtocol::useNetConnectionForRequest(NetConnection*, __CFHTTPMessage*, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 665
16  CFNetwork                           0x0007cdef HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::dispatchConnectionToProtocol(NetConnection*, HTTPProtocol*, HTTPRequestMessage*, unsigned char) + 191
17  CFNetwork                           0x0007c435 HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnection(NetConnection*, unsigned char) + 329
18  CFNetwork                           0x00004f5f HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::enqueueRequestForProtocol(HTTPProtocol*, __CFHTTPMessage*) + 499
19  CFNetwork                           0x0007b2ed HTTPConnectionCache::_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocol(HTTPProtocol*, __CFHTTPMessage*) + 109
20  CFNetwork                           0x0007b5b5 __enqueueRequestForProtocol_block_invoke_0 + 17
21  CFNetwork                           0x000b0133 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 19
22  CoreFoundation                      0x36a0c74d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
23  CFNetwork                           0x000b0593 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 75
24  CFNetwork                           0x0001415d MultiplexerSource::perform() + 189
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00097683 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00096ee9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 213
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00095cb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 647
28  CoreFoundation                      0x36a0cebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
29  CoreFoundation                      0x36a0cd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
30  WebCore                             0x000a5f9f _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 143
31  JavaScriptCore                      0x0017ffb3 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
32  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00011311 _pthread_start + 309
```

Any insight on what the problem might be?

Comment: Seeing the same stacktrace in my app. No clue what can cause it, looks like some bad memory, but since there is not a single line of my app code... Do you use UIWebView's?

Comment: Yes, the app uses UIWebView in different flows. I am seeing these only for users on 6.0 and 6.0.1 and I am seeing many of these. My primary concern is if this is crashing the app or not.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been getting the same crash when using MPMoviePlayerController streaming. ( RAM has always been 60-20meg too )

Comment: do you use AdMob by any chance?